# How to make a dynamic variable in a for loop for javascript for a json return?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, for-loop, dynamic-variables

The API I'm calling has a section of Ingredients I need to pull, and then push to the html page. They are listed as strIngredient1, strIngredient2, strIngredient3... Until 15. What I want to do is loop through each ingredient? I need some sort of dynamic variable I think. Totally not sure.

```js
for (var x = 1; x < 16; x++) {
  if ((drinkResponse.drinks[0].strIngredient + x) !== null) {
    $("#drinkOutput").append($("<p class='drinkData'>Drink Ingredient" + x + " : " + (drinkResponse.drinks[0].strIngredient + x) + "</p>"))
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This is the idea of what I want to do, but currently it returns NaN; when it should be returning a string.

JSON return:

```js
drinks[0] {

  dateModified: "2017-09-02 16:38:19"

  idDrink: "11224"

  strAlcoholic: "Alcoholic"

  strCategory: "Ordinary Drink"

  strCreativeCommonsConfirmed: "No"

  strDrink: "Casino Royale"

  strDrinkAlternate: null

  strDrinkDE: null

  strDrinkES: null

  strDrinkFR: null

  strDrinkThumb: "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/images/media/drink/3qpv121504366699.jpg"

  strDrinkZH-HANS: null

  strDrinkZH-HANT: null

  strGlass: "Whiskey sour glass"

  strIBA: null

  strIngredient1: "Gin"

  strIngredient2: "Lemon juice"

  strIngredient3: "Maraschino liqueur"

  strIngredient4: "Orange bitters"

  strIngredient5: "Egg yolk"

  strIngredient6: null

  strIngredient7: null

  strIngredient8: null

  strIngredient9: null

  strIngredient10: null

  strIngredient11: null

  strIngredient12: null

  strIngredient13: null

  strIngredient14: null

  strIngredient15: null

  strInstructions: "In a shaker half-filled with ice cubes, combine all of the ingredients. Shake well. Strain into a sour glass."

  strInstructionsDE: "In einem Shaker, der halb mit Eiswürfeln gefüllt ist, alle Zutaten vermengen. Gut schütteln. In ein Sour Glas abseihen."

  strInstructionsES: null

  strInstructionsFR: null

  strInstructionsZH-HANS: null

  strInstructionsZH-HANT: null

  strMeasure1: "2 oz "

  strMeasure2: "1/2 oz "

  strMeasure3: "1 tsp "

  strMeasure4: "1 dash "

  strMeasure5: "1 "

  strMeasure6: null

  strMeasure7: null

  strMeasure8: null

  strMeasure9: null

  strMeasure10: null

  strMeasure11: null

  strMeasure12: null

  strMeasure13: null

  strMeasure14: null

  strMeasure15: null

  strTags: null

  strVideo: null

}
```

Comment: Just to understand the logic: `drinkResponse.drinks` is a list of drinks and each has a fixed amount of ingredients `strIngredient`, which however are not provided in the object itself as a list yet as a string property? Would you mind providing a sample object?

Comment: I've added the JSON return to the original question.

Comment: Thanks. You should try, if you can/have access to it, to turn those numerical lists (strMeasure14, strIngredient15) into arrays. Else the structure is kinda limited/flawed. It would also make it more simple to access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to append to the variable name with the value of `x`. You're close, but you need to use bracket notation rather than dot notation.

For example, if `x` is currently 5, you can get the value of `strIngredient5` with `drinkResponse.drinks[0]['strIngredient'+x]` or `` drinkResponse.drinks[0][`strIngredient${x}`] ``.

As Lain pointed out, you can also use `Object.keys` to enumerate all of the keys on the object, then filter for only the keys which start with `strIngredient`:

```
// get all keys on the drink
const allKeys = Object.keys(drinkResponse.drinks[0]);

// now filter for only keys starting with `strIngredient`
const ingredients = allKeys.filter(key => key.startsWith('strIngredient'));

for (const i=0; i<ingredients.length; i++) {
    $("#drinkOutput").append($("<p class='drinkData'>Drink Ingredient" 
    + i + " : " + (drinkResponse.drinks[0][ingredients[i]]) + "</p>"))
}
```

Note that this may not preserve the order, but you can preserve the order by combining the first two examples:

```
for (const i=0; i<ingredients.length; i++) {
    $("#drinkOutput").append($("<p class='drinkData'>Drink Ingredient" 
    + i + " : " + (drinkResponse.drinks[0][`strIngredient${i}`]) + "</p>"))
}
```

Comment: If that is the case he should also loop though the all keys starting with `strIngredient` instead of having a fixed loop from 1 to 15.

Comment: @gcochard I tried that, and now my response is undefined of undefined